# Qual o equivalente em bash do método sys.argv do python?

Tags: python, linux, bash

Em python, quando quero usar uma string dada pelo usuário na linha de comando, eu uso o método `sys.argv`.

Por exemplo, digamos que eu tenha um script chamado `2name.py` que consiste no seguinte código:

```
import sys

lista_nomes = [sys.argv[k] for k in range(len(sys.argv))]

print("Seu segundo nome é {}".format(lista_nomes[2]))
```

No terminal do linux, quando digito:

```
python 2name.py Édson Arantes do Nascimento
```

Retorna:

```
Seu segundo nome é Arantes
```

Gostaria de fazer isso com arquivos bash também, mas não estou conseguindo. Na minha pesquisa encontrei apenas como se usa input do usuário usando o comando `read` (equivalente do `input()` no python), mas quero usar o input que é dado diretamente na linha de comando, assim como o `sys.argv`. Como faço?

Comment: Existe também o `$@` (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0024_0040) - ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41571). Mas no seu caso, usar `$2` me parece ir mais direto ao ponto que vc precisa. E só pra constar, não precisava criar outra lista, era só fazer `print("Seu segundo nome é {}".format(sys.argv[2]))` (ou, se estiver usando Python >= 3.6: `print(f"Seu segundo nome é {sys.argv[2]}")`). Mas se quiser criar uma cópia do `argv`, pode fazer `lista_nomes = sys.argv[:]` ([fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184643))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os argumentos passados na linha de comando para um script Bash são chamados de parâmetros posicionais e são acessados usando variáveis cujo nome é um número (!), assim: o primeiro parâmetro é o `$1`, o segundo `$2`, o terceiro `$3`, assim por diante.

Então se temos o script `2nomes.sh` com o conteúdo:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "O seu sobrenome é $2" 
echo "O seu nome é $1"
```

E o executamos assim:

```sh
./2nomes.sh Lima Barreto
```

A saída será:

```
O seu sobrenome é Barreto
O seu nome é Lima
```

Há outras duas variáveis úteis:

1. `$0` : o caminho do arquivo do script, do jeito que foi executado
2. `$#` : número de argumentos passados na linha de comando

No exemplo acima, `$0` é "./2nomes.sh" e `$#` é 2.

Comment: e já agora `$*` daria `Lima Barreto`